# codegolf.com: Saving Time

Tags: code-golf

From codegolf.com (not loading as of Sept 15, 2011) was one that was driving me crazy. Print to STDOUT a clock of an exacting form, reading time from STDIN and marking an `h` at the hour and `m` at minute (rounded down to a multiple of 5) and an `x` if they overlap, unused ticks are marked with an `o`, so that

```
echo "23:13" | perl script.pl
```

yields

```
        o
    h       o

 o             m

o               o

 o             o

    o       o
        o
```

Mine is:

```
$/=':';($h,$m)=<>;printf'%9s
%5s%8s

%2s%14s

%s%16s

%2s%14s

%5s%8s
%9s',map{qw'o h m x'[2*($_==int$m/5)^$_==$h%12]}map{$_,11-$_}0..5
```

for 136 characters, using Perl. I wish I could get on the site, but I seem to recall that the leaders were under 100, also using Perl. Can someone else beat it?

Comment: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=811919

Comment: A fascinating read :)

Comment: @Peter, its the goldmine! Thanks for finding that, I wonder if mine can adapt their techniques?

Comment: What do you mean, "adapt"? Same golf, same solutions, no?

Comment: @J B, I was mostly proud of the way that I selected the marker, so I had been hoping to mesh their formatter with it. The reason I haven't posted it is that it is still many chars longer than those mad geniuses from the article.

Comment: Is there a serious reason why to use something in such lemon shape, instead of a circle?

Comment: @userunknown: The original task was probably designed using a wider font.

Answer (score 3):

### Golfscript, 75 bytes

Inspired by [the article linked in the comments](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=811919).

```
':'/{~}/5/:m;12%:h;"XXXXXXXXXXXX"{..318\%9/' '*@12%.h=2*\m=+'omhx'=@85/n*}%
```

The `XXXXXXXXXXXX` part represents 12 bytes of data, some of them unprintable, and should be replaced with the byte sequence `120 47 253 22 194 9 183 44 196 55 125 246`.

For convenience, here is a base64 encoded version:

```
JzonL3t+fS81LzptOzEyJTpoOyJ4L/0Wwgm3LMQ3ffYiey4uMzE4XCU5LycgJypAMTIlLmg9Mipc
bT0rJ29taHgnPUA4NS9uKn0l
```

**Example run:**

```
$ echo -n "JzonL3t+fS81LzptOzEyJTpoOyJ4L/0Wwgm3LMQ3ffYiey4uMzE4XCU5LycgJypAMTIlLmg9MipcbT0rJ29taHgnPUA4NS9uKn0l" | base64 -d > saving-time.gs
$ ls -l saving-time.gs 
-rw-r--r-- 1 ahammar ahammar 75 2012-01-29 17:31 saving-time.gs
$ ruby golfscript.rb saving-time.gs <<< "15:37"
        o
    o       o

 o             o

o               h

 o             o

    m       o
        o
```

Answer (score 2):

### C, <strike>259</strike> <strike>244</strike> 163 chars

Replaced command line argument with stdin (as required, also ends up shorter).
Removed support for minutes above 59 - a waste of 3 characters.
The code is shown with line breaks and indentation, but characters were counted without them.

```
main(i,h,m,x){
    scanf("%d:%d",&h,&m);
    for(i=0;i<12;
        printf("%*c","IEHBNAPBNEHI"[i++]-64,"ohmx"[(x==h%12)+2*(x==m/5)]))
        x=i%2?puts("\n"+(i%10==1)),11-i/2:i/2;
    puts("");
}
```

Older attempt (using ANSI escape codes), 244 chars:

```
f(x,y)char*y;{printf("\033[%d%c",x>0?x:-x,y[x<0]);}
main(i,h,m,x){
    char*v="HIJJJJIGFFFFPKJHFDCCDFHJ";
    f(i=f(scanf("%d:%d",&h,&m),"J")*0,v);
    for(;i<12;i++)
        (x=v[i+12]-72)&&f(x,"CD"),
        f(v[i]-72,"BA"),
        putchar("omhx"[2*(i==h%12)+(i==m%60/5)]);
    f(i,"B");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python, 175 chars

```
h,m=map(int,raw_input().split(':'))
S=([' ']*17+['\n'])*11
for i in range(12):p=1j**(i/3.);S[98+int(8.5*p.imag)-18*int(5*p.real)]='ohmx'[2*(i==m/5)+(i==h%12)]
print''.join(S),
```

Doesn't beat your Perl code, but maybe a more concise language with built in complex numbers (or trig functions) could use this idea to do better.

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 226 chars

```
h,p,s=raw_input().split(':'),['o']*12,[0,11,1,10,2,9,3,8,4,7,5,6]
a,b=int(h[0])%12,int(h[1])/5
p[a],p[b]='h','m' if a!=b else 'x'
print '%9s\n%5s%8s\n\n %s%14s\n\n%s%16s\n\n %s%14s\n\n%5s%8s\n%9s'%tuple([p[i] for i in s])
```

Usage: run 'python script.py' then type the required time. (Ex: 09:45)

Output:

```
        o
    o       o

 o             o

x               o

 o             o

    o       o
        o
```

Answer (score 0):

My perl solution:

```
use POSIX;$/=':';@ss=(8,4,1,0,1,4,8);@sn=(0,7,13,15,13,7,0);$h=<stdin>;
$m=<stdin>;if($h>12){$h=$h-12;}$m=floor($m/5);
for($c=0;$c<7;$c++){for($s=0;$s<$ss[$c];$s++){printf(" ");}
$ac='o';if($h>5&&$h-6==6-$c){$ac='h';}if((($m>5)&&$m-6==6-$c)||($m==$c)&&($c==0)){
if($h>5&&$h-6==6-$c){$ac='x';}else{$ac='m';}}
print($ac);for($s=0;$s<$sn[$c];$s++){printf(" ");}$bc='o';if($h<6&&$h==$c){$bc='h';}
if($m<6&&$m==$c){if($h<6&&$h==$c){$bc='x';}else{$bc='m';}}
if($sn[$c]){print($bc);}printf("\n");if($c&&($c!=5)){printf("\n");}}
```

### 527 bytes

My C solution:

```
main(){int x[]={8,4,1,0,1,4,8},y[]={0,7,13,15,13,7,0}
,h,m,z,c,s;scanf("%d:%d",&h,&m);h>12?h-=12:h;m/=5;
for(c=0;c<7;c++){for(s=0;s<x[c];s++){printf(" ");}z='o';
if(h>5&h-6==6-c){z='h';}if((m>5&m-6==6-c)|(m==c)&!c){
z='m';if(h>5&h-6==6-c){z='x';}}printf("%c",z);
for(s=0;s<y[c];s++){printf(" ");}z='o';if(h<6&h==c){
z='h';}if(m<6&m==c){z='m';if(h<6&h==c){z='x';}}
if(y[c]){printf("%c",z);}printf("\n");if(c&&(c!=5)){printf("\n");}}}
```

440 bytes

Comment: a quick suggestion on the Perl: you don't need posix, you can read from stdin with simply `<>` and I don't think you need to `printf` the way you are using it, `print` will work :)

Answer (score 0):

### Scala 327 chars

```
object C extends App{
val R=List(2,4,6,8,10)
val r=1::R:::11::R.reverse
val C=List(3,6,12,18,21)
val c=1::C:::21::C.reverse
def p(n:Int,i:Char){
val z=r(n)
val s=c((n+3)%12)
printf("[%d;%dH"+i,z,s)}
val t=readLine.split(":")
val h=t(0).toInt%12
val m=t(1).toInt/5
(0 to 11).map(x=>p(x,'o'))
p(h,'h')
p(m,'m')
if(h==m)p(h,'x')}
```

#### in use with a proper circle shape, not your lemon-XXXX:

```
clear  && echo 5:43 | scala C 
           o
     o           o

  o                 o

o                    o

  m                 o

     o           h
           o
```

#### ungolfed:

```
object Clock {
 val R = List (2,4,6,8,10)
 val r = 1 :: R ::: 11 :: R.reverse
 val C = List (3,6,12,18,21)
 val c = 1 :: C ::: 22 :: C.reverse

 def pos (n: Int, i: Char)={
   val z = r (n) 
   val s = c ((n+3) % 12) 
   printf ("[%d;%dH" + i, z, s)
 }

 def main (args: Array [String]) {
   val t = args (0).split (":")
   val h = t (0).toInt % 12
   val m = t (1).toInt /  5
   (0 to 11).map (x=> pos (x, 'o'))
   pos (h, 'h') 
   pos (m, 'm')
   if (h == m) pos (h, 'x')
  }
}
```

Uses Ansi-Code for output at pos(y,x). Since we only need 5 Minutes accuracy, precalculated values for x and y seem to be shorter than handling sin and cos functions with their import.

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 176 characters

```
o=map(ord,' .@Set~lWC2&!/0ABTUfgu')
h,m=map(int,raw_input().split(':'))
print''.join([' ',['\n','ohmx'[2*(i==o[m/5])+(i==o[h%12])]][i in o[:12]]][i in o]for i in range(24,127))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Perl 131 characters**

```
<>=~/:/;$h=$`%12;$m=$'/5;printf'%9s
%12$5s%8s

%11$2s%14s

%10$s%16s

%9$2s%14s

%8$5s%8s
%9s',map$_^$h?$_^$m?o:'m':$h^$m?h:x,0..11
```